# cannot file:// requests,cross origin request are only supported for http://

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cors, phonegap

I have developed a Phonegap application using the Ionic html element.
Everything is working fine with Android app, but in iOS it is throwing the error:  "Can not access cross origin request."

[image: Console errors]

Though I have added one tag in config.xml which is allow-navigation, in which I have provided my api url. But still it is getting the same error.

Tried with "*", "http://*/*", but still not working.

Comment: This looks to be know reopened issue in PhoneGap: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/98

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the WKWebView plugin for iOS? There [known issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10143) with xhr requests in WKWebView because of CORS restrictions. There are a couple possible work arounds.

You could install the [local-webserver plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/local-webserver) so all your assests are served through http:// instead of file:// URIs.

There's also [Ionic's fork](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) of the WKWebView plugin which supports XHR requests.

Comment: No I am not using WKWebView plugin for iOS. :(

Comment: I uses apache cordova, but why is it still blocked? And it said 'Blocked a frame with origin null'.

Answer (score 1):

For Cordova iOS 6+ just need to install the following plugin.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/AraHovakimyan/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix
```

This plugin does not depend on any other additional plugins and does not require additional permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the ionic-webview-plugin?

If this is the case you have to remove the `file:///` part of the native url.

> The file:// portion of the URL must be removed in order for the resource to load correctly. You can do this manually, but as of ionic-angular@3.2.0, we provide a quick function that will handle this automatically.

`window.Ionic.WebView.convertFileSrc()`

https://blog.ionicframework.com/wkwebview-for-all-a-new-webview-for-ionic/

I just stumbled over this myself :)